# Javascript split is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, string, split

Hey friends i am using javascript sdk to post on users friends wall with jQuery facebook multi friend selector however i am getting this error friendId.split is not a function. Here is my code

```
function recommendToFriend(pic, url, friendId, fromName)
{
    alert(friendId);
    var friendList ;
    pFriend = new Array();
    pFriend = friendId.split(',');
    for( x in pFriend )
    {
        alert(pFriend[x]);
        var publish = {
            method:'feed',
            picture:pic,
            link:url,
            name:'SHARP Product Recommend',
            caption: fromName + 'has recommend a product to you via Sharp Expert lounge',
        };

        FB.api('/'+pFriend[x]+'/feed', 'post', publish, function(resp) {
            if( !response || response.error )
                alert('Unable to share');
            else
                alert('Successfully posted to firends wall');
        });
    }
}
```

In alert box i got comma seperated friend ids so i use split function post on each users wall seperately i dont know whats wrong here please help me

Comment: Most probably this is because `friendId` is not a string but an array.

Comment: What does `console.dir(friendId)` or `console.log(typeof friendId)` tell you? `alert` is the worse debugging method you could have possible chosen.

Comment: console.log(typeof(friendId)) returns object

Comment: Then you should address a certain property or iterate it to get the values.

Comment: how can i iterate through in objects like we use forin loop for arrays is there  any equivalent for objects?

Comment: Yes. `for (var i in friendId)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse JS Objects like this

```
for (var key in friendid) {
   var obj = friendid[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

**alternate**

```
for( var x in friendId )
 {
  alert(friendId[x]); // this would be your desired value
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Most probably `friendID` is already an array. If you call `alert` the array is converted to a string and becomes a comma separated list of values.

Note that converting an array to a string is not the same as calling `JSON.stringify` (where you get also brackets and double quotes around elements when they're strings)

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript `split()` function is for the type string ie for eg.

```
var friendid='1,34,67';
```

As  VisioN says, when you alert an array you get comma separated values.

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)