# Query in php fails with get and spaces

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, get

Hoping someone can help. I have dynamic drop-downs that have been working great until I added a new item with a space in it. It's confusing me because my second drop-down has items with spaces and the query runs fine with those but the first drop-down fails. I've tried to find any differences that would cause one to fail but I just can't see it. It's been a mixture of scripts that I found and I'm really new to Javascript and PHP so I'm lost. I hope someone can point me to my error. Here's the code I think you need to see The first script is the one that controls the dropdown that is failing the second one is working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxFunction()
{

var ddstring = document.getElementById("name");
var ddindex = ddstring.options[ddstring.selectedIndex].value;

if (ddindex != 0){  
var httpxml;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
          try
                    {
                 httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
            catch (e)
                    {
                try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
                catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
            }
  }
function stateck() 
    {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {
//alert(httpxml.responseText);
var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
var myarray=myarray.split(",");
for(j=document.searchform.type.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.searchform.type.remove(j);
}
for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");

optn.text = myarray[i];
optn.value = myarray[i];
document.searchform.type.options.add(optn);
} 
{
var optn2 = document.createElement("OPTION");

optn2.text = "Select Type";
optn2.value = '%';
document.searchform.type.options.add(optn2,0);
} 
{
document.searchform.type.disabled=false;
document.searchform.type.selectedIndex = 0;
var defaultdd = "<?php echo $_SESSION['type'] ?>";

if (defaultdd != ""){
document.getElementById('s2').value = defaultdd;
if (defaultdd != "%"){
AjaxFunction2(); 
}

}
}

  }
}
var url="dd.php";
var cat_id=document.getElementById('name').value;
url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
//alert(url);
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
}

else {
    document.searchform.type.selectedIndex = 0;
    document.searchform.subcat.selectedIndex = 0;
    document.searchform.type.disabled=true;
    document.searchform.subcat.disabled=true;       
}
}
</script>




<script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxFunction2()
{
var httpxml;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
          try
                    {
                 httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
            catch (e)
                    {
                try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
                catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
            }
  }
function stateck() 
    {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {
//alert(httpxml.responseText);
var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
var myarray=myarray.split(",");
for(j=document.searchform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.searchform.subcat.remove(j);
}


for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myarray[i];
optn.value = myarray[i];
document.searchform.subcat.options.add(optn);

} 
{
var optn2 = document.createElement("OPTION");

optn2.text = "Select Series";
optn2.value = '%';
document.searchform.subcat.options.add(optn2,0);
}
{
document.searchform.subcat.disabled=false;
document.searchform.subcat.selectedIndex = 0;

var defaultdd = "<?php echo $_SESSION['subcat'] ?>";
if (defaultdd != ""){
document.getElementById('s3').value = defaultdd;
}
}

      }
    }
    var url="dd2.php";
var cat_id=document.getElementById('name').value;
var cat_id2=document.getElementById('s2').value;
url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
url=url+"&cat_id2="+cat_id2;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
//alert(url);
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
  }
</script>
```

The Form Elements:

```
<form name="searchform" method='POST' action='?'>
  <table width="534" border="1" cellspacing="10" ID="tdspace">
    <tr>
      <td>Manufacturer: </td>
      <td><select name=name id='name' onchange=AjaxFunction();>
        <option value='%'>Select One</option>
        <?Php
try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. $dbname, $username, $password);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}

$sql="SELECT Distinct Manufacturer FROM `tbl_Printers` order by `Manufacturer` asc ";
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {

        if ($row[Manufacturer] == $_SESSION['name'])

        $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
    else  
        $selected = "";
echo "<option value=$row[Manufacturer] $selected>$row[Manufacturer]</option>";
if( $_SESSION['type'])
{ echo '<script type="text/javascript">AjaxFunction()</script>';
}
}
?>
        <?php
    if ( $_SESSION['name'] == ""){ $namevalue = 'None Selected';}
    else {$namevalue = $_SESSION['name'];}

    if ( $_SESSION['type'] == "%"){ $typevalue = 'None Selected';}
    else {$typevalue = $_SESSION['type'];}

    if ( $_SESSION['subcat'] == "%"){ $subvalue = 'None Selected';}
    else {$subvalue = $_SESSION['subcat'];}
?>
      </select></td>
      <td>Manufacturer:<span style="color:cyan"> <?php echo $namevalue;?></span></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Type: </td>
      <td><select name=type id='s2' onchange=AjaxFunction2(); disabled=true>
        <option value='%' selected>Select Type</option>
      </select></td>
      <td>Product Type:<span style="color:magenta"> <?php echo $typevalue?></span></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Printer Catagory:</td>
      <td><select name=subcat id='s3' disabled=true>
        <option value='%' selected>Select Series</option>
      </select></td>
      <td>Printer Series:<span style="color:yellow"> <?php echo $subvalue;?></span></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="27" colspan="2" ID="centered" style="padding-left:90px"><br />        <input type=submit onclick="s3.disabled=false; s2.disabled=false" class="quick-search-button btn"/></td>
      <td>Records Found:<span style="color:black; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"> <?php echo $_SESSION['totalrecords'];?></span></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="28" colspan="3" style="text-align:center"><br />
        *Manufacturer is Manditory, all other fields optional. </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <br />
<br />

<p><div id="finish">

</p></div>
</form>
```

This is the php page that is supposed to return the results for the first drop-down although the second drop-down form is practically identical and works:

```
<?Php
@$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
//$cat_id=2;


$dbhost_name = "localhost";
$database = "database";// database name
$username = "username"; // user name
$password = "password"; // password 

//////// Do not Edit below /////////
try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
$str='';
$sql="SELECT Distinct Type FROM `tbl_Printers` where Manufacturer='$cat_id' order by Type asc";
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
$str=$str . "$row[Type]".",";
}
$str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string

//$main = array($str);
echo json_encode($str); 
//echo $str;
?>
```

I appreciate any help, I've tried searching and normally I don't ask for help but this one is just to far beyond my understanding.

For the moment I have replaced all of my queires to read like this (There are a lot of them considering the paging...) I don't see this as an answer though just a work around.

```
"SELECT Distinct Type FROM `tbl_Printers` where Manufacturer Like CONCAT('%', '$cat_id', '%') order by Type asc"
```

The thanks go to Vigour for pointing me in the correct direction. Unfortunately I can't select a comment as the answer or post an answer for my own question until tomorrow because of my reputation,  but thank you so much for finding the issue.

The line of code causing the issue was:

```
echo "<option value=$row[Manufacturer] $selected>$row[Manufacturer]</option>";
```

It needed to be changed to this to add the quotes as needed and still select the proper saved item:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['Manufacturer']."' ".$selected." >" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: What actually gets sent to the browser when you View Source and look at the section where the dropdown is supposed to be?  Sometimes Error Messages will display in the <options> fields.

Comment: When I look at the source code from the browser nothing shows in the form options except the first drop-down lists values. There are no errors on the page that I can see. It's just as if the query ran and returned no results. But as soon as I select a value with no spaces from the first drop down the second is populated.

Comment: I jsut noticed on the page.. I have a section that posts the values for each drop down selection and the second word is not being captured. So if you choose Pitney Bowes only Pitney is being posted back to the page. As expected though a two word selection from the second drop down is being posted back with both words.

Answer (score 0):

Better test it, but I think the JS should replace the empty string with + sign in order to pass it correctly:

Replace:
var cat_id=document.getElementById('name').value;

With: 
var cat_id=document.getElementById('name').value.replace('/ /gi','+');

Comment: There's an error in the JS when selecting a spaced value:

[23:10:26.259] TypeError: myarray.split is not a function @ http://www.oemalternatives.ca/printersearch.php:53

Comment: Check out the info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583055/javascript-split-is-not-a-function  might help to debug the problem.

Comment: What does aler(myarray); return after var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);?

Comment: OK so the issue seems to be when the script is retrieving the value from the element. I made it post an alert after: 
    var cat_id=document.getElementById('name').value; 
with the var cat_id and only the first word is being captured. So I guess I need to figure out how to capture both words or why it's only capturing one.........

Comment: Found the problem: <option value=Kyocera Mita >Kyocera Mita</option>

Should be <option value="Kyocera Mita" >Kyocera Mita</option>

Answer (score 0):

You should add the option values with quotation marks, otherwise the spaced values will not be passed.

```
 <option value="Kyocera Mita" >Kyocera Mita</option>
```